# Where is the Core of Unisystem?

Tags: product-identification, system-introduction, unisystem

I'm trying to expand the range of universal/generic systems I'm acquainted with, and took a look at Unisystem. I had a very superficial run-in with it in one of its licensed-franchise forms some years ago, and would now like to take a look at it in its pure, setting-agnostic form. But when searching publications related to the system, I am having trouble finding a book that would be the equivalent of a system core (similar to the role of Cypher System Rulebook of Cypher, the EABA 2.0 book of EABA, the Basic Set of GURPS, and the like).

What book should I look towards for acquainting myself with the system in its most basic, generic form?

Comment: I think the system introduction tag is a better fit than the product identification tag, but I'll leave both in.

Comment: @Akixkisu Both seem of use for describing what this is focused on, yes, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Unisystem is a proprietary engine. There is no public core, but...

Unisystem was designed by C.J. Carella for the games *Witchcraft* and *Armageddon*, but the game developer and publisher Eden Studios brought an exclusive license to the system and its derivatives, using it to release updated editions of *Witchcraft* and *Armageddon* in addition to several of their own products. Some of these, like *Buffy the Vampire Slayer*, use a cinematic version of Unisystem with a less complex skill and combat resolution engine. (Unfortunately, the company itself seems to have gone radio silent for several years now.)

With all that said, ***All Flesh Must Be Eaten* is a good place to start if you're looking for something like a "core" to Unisystem**. It was the first product Eden Studios published under the engine and it contains the most explanation of how the system works, such as how to construct a monster, and bills itself as widely adaptable.

If you're looking to write a hack in a genre where Unisystem has already been used, games in that genre are a good next step; if you're interested in "cinematic Unisystem", picking up any of those books, in-genre or out, will also get you an appendix with instructions for converting from classic Unisystem.